# Designing complex table layout using html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design the following table using html and css how do I proceed with it. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and where you got stuck

Comment: You can probably accomplish this just with an html table and strategic use of `colspan` and `rowspan`. That should get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will save you from having to use nested tables. The trick is that you really have *four* rows, not three, and make use of `colspan` and `rowspan`.

Note that you need to set a `height` for the `td` in order to ensure they are even.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>

   <td>
   <table>

   <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Th</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>Th</td>
        <td>Th</td>
    </tr>   
  <tr>
        <td>Th</td>
        <td>Th</td>
    </tr>   
   </table>
   </td>

        <td>Th</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table 
{
width:100%;
height:100px;
text-align:center;
 border:2px solid gray;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
td
{
border:2px solid gray;
}

.container
{
  width:100%;
}
.container .header
{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:#5076BB;
}
.container .slider
{
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  background:#5076BB;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/1cdzy94k/1/)

[**UPDATED DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/p1otm7t5/)

Comment: How do I divide the last column into two equal parts horizontally

Comment: wait @user93 i will help u

Comment: Y @user93 I put answer ,.. Why are u changing thanks

Comment: sorry but the solution without nested table was what I required

Answer (score 0):

Read the tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

In particular read the part about the attributes rowspan="" and colspan=""

Example:

`<td colspan="2">This table data will span two columns</td>`

`<td rowspan="2">This table data will span two rows</td>`

Comment: This does not provide a complete solution to the question. If you have a suggestion you should comment. If you don't have the rep to comment, then you should keep quiet or go earn the rep (with good answers)

Comment: @musefan, OP asked "how do I proceed with it". OP did not ask for the code to be handed to the OP for copy and paste. I told OP how to proceed and gave OP a link to a tutorial.

Comment: Question asking for tutorials are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Answers that don't solve the problem are not good answers, so you get a downvote. You should not answer by just giving suggestions, you should always provide complete answers

Comment: @musefan, I answered the question OP gave, do you downvote the question as well as this answer?

Comment: [This is what happens when you run your code](https://jsfiddle.net/sux6pk39/), is that what the OP is trying to get? No. So your answer does not solve the problem. That's why you get a downvote

Comment: @musefan, user93 asked "how do I proceed with it", not: here is the code you need, please copy and paste.